# ASP Form to Text file

Tags: text, asp-classic, vbscript

I have written some code from what I can gather from online sources to submit some text from a form into a text file, now I do not know what I am missing but nothing is coming through to the text file, I am guessing it might be something to do with maybe folder paths but I am not sure, just looking for some direction on this.

My ASP Form Code is:

```
<form method="get" action="simpleform.asp">

<br/>
<i>Please include your initials and date with the bug report</i> 
<br/>
<br/>
<b>Bug</b> <input type="text" name="bug">

<input type="submit" value="Submit Bug Report">
</form>
<br/>
```

ASP Code to comit the text to the file is this:

```
<html>
<body>
Thanks for the report! To report another bug <a href="BugReportPage.asp">click         here</a>.

<%
Dim idea

dim fs,f

set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set f=fs.OpenTextFile("G:\General\EM_Wiki\WikiBug\bugreport.txt",8,true)

idea= Request.QueryString("bug")


f.WriteLine(bug)
f.Close
set f=nothing
set fs=nothing

%>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that makes sense to someone and that you can point me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You aren't writing the correct variable to the file.

`f.WriteLine(bug)` should be `f.WriteLine(idea)`

If you turn on "Option Explicit", it is easier to diagnose these kinds of problems.  Here's the page that shows you how to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524870(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

your actual content is in variable `idea`, not in `bug`. `bug` is just an index of query string. Also you may need to `flush` your stream.

Use the `flush` method before closing file , e `f.flush()`

```
f.WriteLine(idea)
//your more writing
f.flush()
f.Close
```

here's the msdn link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx